# Chrome and Firefox's actual css value different for padding

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, html-table

I have a weird problem where chrome and firefox both point to the same stylesheet, however in chrome when I inspect the element, it shows that the padding definition is padding: 5px 5px;

however in firefox, when I use firebug and inspect the element, it shows padding: 5px;

this obviously gives different results in both browsers. weird thing is again its the same stylesheet, and in both they point to the same line of code. Any ideas here?

the padding is applied to a table element's td tag if that matters. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`padding: 5px 5px;` is the same as `padding: 5px;`

http://jsfiddle.net/4fmq8/

`padding: 5px;` sets a 5px padding on all 4 sides.

`padding: 5px 5px;` sets 5px padding for the top and bottom (the first 5) and 5px for the left and right (the 2nd 5).

As you can see, that's the same thing.

Comment: ahh, makes sense. interestingly though, when i manually change it to padding: 5px; in chrome, it renders differently, and fixes a problem that is apparent in it. Thanks though, that clears that up.
EDIT: nvm solved it, thanks.